# Equality of continuous functions of bounded and unbounded variations

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure, bounded-variation

Suppose $f:[0,1] \to \mathbb{R}$ is continuous and has infinite total variation on any interval $[a,b] \subset [0,1]$ with $a <b$. Suppose $g$ is a function of bounded variation on $[0,1]$ and is continuous on $[0,1]$ i.e. $g \in BV([0,1]) \cap C([0,1])$. If $m$ denotes the Lebesgue measure on $\mathbb{R}$, is it true that $m(A)=0$ where $A \subset [0,1]$ is the set where $f$ and $g$ are equal?

I intuitively think that there are counterexamples using 'too bumpy' functions on fat cantor sets. But I am having a hard time constructing them rigorously. Can anyone help, please?

Comment: Sorry, but this is your homework, not ours. We are willing to help you figure it out, but not do it for you. Indicate what you have attempted and where you run into trouble, and you will likely get hints on how to proceed. And if your answer is "I don't know how to start", then the answer is you start by reading your textbook and class materials carefully, and giving great thought to them. And then you play around with various things until you build up enough familiarity with the problem that something clicks.

Comment: This is not part of the homework, first of all. This is a question that I have been thinking about when I first read about functions with bounded variations. I have tried to come up with counterexamples and failed that is why I am asking it here. I still think this statement is not true and we can actually provide a counterexample.

Answer (score 1):

A way to construct such.

Pick $H$ your favorite continuous periodic function on $[0,1]$ that is not of BV on any subinterval. Any continuous function that is differentiable nowhere or on a set of measure zero will do since BV functions are differentiable ae on any interval.

Eg Riemann function $\sum_{n \ge 1} \frac{\sin 2\pi n^2x}{n^2}$ which is differentiable only at countably many points, or a Weierstrass function $G(2x)=\sum_{n \ge 0}(99/100)^n \cos (7^n 2\pi x)$ to make it of period $1$ and assume wlog (by adding a constant if needed) that $H(0)=H(1)=1$, while $|H(x)| \le M$ for $x \in \mathbb R$

For any $a<b$ let $H_{a,b}(x)=H(\frac {x-a}{b-a})$ the function with variables scaled so $H_{a,b}(a)=H_{a,b}(b)=1, |H_{a,b}| \le M, x \in [a,b]$ and of course $H_{a,b}$ is not of bounded variation on any subinterval of $[a,b]$

Consider a fat Cantor set, so a compact $C$ st $[0,1]-C=\cup (a_n, b_n), m(C)>0$ and $C$ has empty interior, and arrange the disjoint intervals $I_n=(a_n,b_n)$ in decreasing order of size, so at step $N$ we write $[0,1]=C_N \cup_{n \le N}I_N$, so if $(a_{jN}, b_{jN})$ are corresponding intervals $I_n$ in order from $0$ to $1$ now, we have $C_N=[0, a_{1N}]\cup [b_{1N}, a_{2N}]..\cup [b_{NN},1]$

Define two functions $f_N, g_N$ as follows; we first construct $F_N, G_N$ by taking a linear function from $0$ to $H_{a_{1N}, b_{a1N}}(a_{1N})=1$ on $[0, a_{1N}]$ then on $[a_{1N},b_{1N}]$ making the functions $F_N,G_N$ constant or $H_{a_{1N}, b_{1N}}(x)$ respectively, then making both increase linearly from $1$ to $2$ on the interval $[b_{1N}, a_{2N}]$ and then either take the constant $2$ or $H_{a_{2N}, b_{2N}}(x)+1$ on $[a_{2N},b_{2N}]$ etc while at the end take as $f_N=F_N/2^N, g_N=G_N/2^N$ and then take $f=\sum f_N, g=\sum g_N$

Note that by construction $|f_N| \le (N+1)/2^N, |g_N| \le (M+N)/2^N$ so clearly $f,g$ are well defined and continuous and $f(a_n)=g(a_n), f(b_n)=g(b_n)$ while $f$ is monotonic since each $f_N$ is so $f$ is BV and $f=g$ on the accumulation set of $a_n,b_n$ which is $C$ by definition, so $f=g$ on a set of positive measure.

But on each $(a_n,b_n)$ we have that for $N \ge n$ that $g_N(x)=\frac{H_{a_{n}, b_{n}}(x)+c_{nN}}{2^N}$, while for $N <n$ we have that $g_1,...g_{n-1}$ are increasing so $g$ restricted to $[a_n, b_n]$ is of the type $c_n+h_n(x)+d_nH_{a_{n}, b_{n}}(x)$ where $c_n, d_n >0$ are constants and $h_n$ is increasing, hence $g$ cannot have bounded variation on any subinterval of $[a_n,b_n]$

But now $C$ has empty interior so if $[a,b]$ is any subinterval of $[0,1]$ it cannot be included in it so it must have interior points in common with $(a_n,b_n)$ for some $n$ so it must have a subinterval in common with $(a_n,b_n)$ so it cannot be of bounded variation of $[a,b]$ since then it would be of bounded variation on a subinterval of $(a_n,b_n)$, so we are done!